# I can not open phpmyadmin window

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have installed `mysql` and mysql server 5.7.20.

I can connect to `mysql` in terminal using `mysql -u root -p`

I have also installed php 7.0.22

I have also installed apache2 2.4.18

and when I try to open : `http://localhost/phpmyadmin/`

I got file like this ...

```
<?php

/* vim: set expandtab sw=4 ts=4 sts=4: */
/**
* Main loader script
*
* @package PhpMyAdmin
*/

/**
* Gets some core libraries and displays a top message if required
 */
require_once 'libraries/common.inc.php';

/**
* display Git revision if requested
*/
require_once 'libraries/display_git_revision.lib.php';
require_once 'libraries/Template.class.php';

/**
* pass variables to child pages
*/
```

..........

I can not understand.

What is the actual issue

Please help me if you have any idea.

Comment: Which Local Server are you using ? and Can you Open Sample php file in `http://localhost/test.php`  ?

Comment: Looks like your web server isn't configured to process PHP files through the PHP interpreter. Look into how to set up your server with PHP.

Comment: So should I uninstall php and install it again ?

Comment: @SachinShah yes uninstall and install it in a proper way.. it will work then

Comment: @SachinShah You can use XAMPP Apache server that will install everything for you though

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP code is not being executed, instead code shows on the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) or [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html) servers?

Comment: I have tried also but apache and mysql will automatically stops

Comment: It is possibly because you have already installed mysql seperately and it must have occupied the required port for xampp.
First try uninstalling the mysql server you have installed explicitly, delete your temp files using %temp% in run, and restart then reinstall the XAMPP, if the same isnt working, post installation share the info in the log file.

Answer (score 0):

[WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) or [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html) is the better option but if you still want to install `Apache`, `PHP` and `MySql` separately then you can follow below link that given step by step procedure of installing and testing all :-

https://docs.moodle.org/33/en/Manual_install_on_Windows_7_with_Apache_and_MySQL